# play frame work and scala : pass parameter value from one page to another

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to pass parameter with a object to  page from another page

Here is my router

```
GET    /Location/edit:locid             controllers.Locations.editLocation(locid:Int)
```

I`m calling from this page

```
@import models._
@import play.api.Play.current
@import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._

@index(Messages("application.name")+" | Locations"){



<div class="container" style="float:left">

    <div class="menu_title">
        <h1>Locations</h1>
    </div>  

    <div class="menu_box">
        <a href="@routes.Locations.locationc"><p>Add new +</p></a>
    </div>      


  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Location ID</th>
        <th>Location Name</th>
        <th>Ref No</th>
            <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>



        @for(l <- Location.findAllLocations()){
        <form action="@routes.Locations.editLocation(l.id)">
          <tr>
          <input type="hidden" name="locid" value="@l.id"/> 
        <td>@l.id</td>
        <td>@l.name</td>
        <td>@l.ref</td>
         <td>   <p id="subbut">  <input type="submit" id="logbut" class="btn btn-default" value='Edit'></p></td>

         </tr>
         </form>     

        }


    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


}
```

Here is the controller method i use

```
def editLocation(locid: Int) = Action { implicit request =>
  request.session.get("mysession").map { user =>
    val form = if (request.flash.get("error").isDefined) 
                 locationForm.bind(request.flash.data) 
               else 
                 locationForm
    Location.findLocationBydb(locid).map { location =>
       Ok(views.html.location.editLocation(form,location))
    }.getOrElse(NotFound)
  }.getOrElse {
    Redirect(routes.Users.loginUser())
  }

}
```

here is the Model

```
 def findLocationBydb(id:Int)={
   var locations= new ListBuffer[Location]()
   val conn = DB.getConnection()
   try {
     val stmt = conn.createStatement
     val rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from m_locations where idLoc='"+id+"'  ")
     if (rs.next()) {
       locations+= Location(rs.getInt("idLoc"),rs.getString("LocDes"),rs.getString("LocRef"));
     }
   } finally {
     conn.close()
   }
 locations.toList.head
}
```

But I got this Error

> Read from stdout:
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\SimpleRequest22-DBCon_Session\app\controllers\Locations.scala:71:
>   value map is not a member of models.Location
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\SimpleRequest22-DBCon_Session\app\controllers\Locations.scala:71:
>   value map is not a member of models.Location Read from stdout:
>   Location.findLocationBydb(locid).map { location =>
>                                   Location.findLocationBydb(locid).map { location => Read from stdout: ^
>                                                                    ^ Read from stdout:
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\SimpleRequest22-DBCon_Session\app\views\location\editLocation.scala.html:7:
>   not found: value loc
>   D:\PROJECTS\test\SimpleRequest22-DBCon_Session\app\views\location\editLocation.scala.html:7:
>   not found: value loc Read from stdout: @(loc:Location) @(loc:Location)
>   Read from stdout: ^
>           ^ Read from stdout: two errors found two errors found Read from stdout: (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
>   (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you get is `map` is not member of `Location`. You are trying to use `map` on Location that is returned by `Location.findLocationBydb`.

Instead of

```
Location.findLocationBydb(locid).map { location =>
  Ok(views.html.location.editLocation(form,location))
}
```

use

```
val location = Location.findLocationBydb(locid)
Ok(views.html.location.editLocation(form,location))
```

Comment: Its not working dude, I got this error after edit it like you given :  
`too many arguments for method apply: (locationForm: play.api.data.Form[models.Location])(implicit flash: play.api.mvc.Flash, implicit lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable in class editLocation`

Comment: @BuwanekaSumanasekara, that issue is not clear from the error messages that you have given. I see that you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends I got the solution my self, 
First I change the controller method like this

```
 def editLocation(locid: Int) = Action { implicit request =>                  
                request.session.get("mysession").map { user =>

                        val form = if (request.flash.get("error").isDefined) 
                            locationForm.bind(request.flash.data) 
                            else 
                                locationForm
                                Ok(views.html.location.editLocation(locationForm,Location.findLocationBydb(locid)))

                }.getOrElse {
                    Redirect(routes.Users.loginUser())
                }             
  }
```

And also I have changed the view page  (editLocation.scala.html) by

```
@(locationForm: Form[Location],loc:Location)(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)
```